# Progress Dialog inside OnSuccess method, Firebase-Firestore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am uploading an ArrayList to firebase-storage and then retrieving download URL and then storing custom data object into firebase-firestore. I dont know when to stop the progress dialog.

```
public void uploadNotesToSTORAGE(final ArrayList<NoteItem> nItems, final Activity activity) {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading picture...");
    dialog.show();

    for (int i = 0; i < nItems.size(); i++) {
        final String id = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "";
        StorageReference reference = mStorageRef.child("notes/" + id);
        String filePath = nItems.get(i).getFilePath();
        final int finalI = i;
        final int finalI1 = i;
        reference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                StorageReference reference = mStorageRef.child("notes/" + id);
                reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri dUri) {
                        nItems.get(finalI).setId(id);
                        nItems.get(finalI).setDownloadLink(dUri + "");
                        db.collection("notes").document().set(nItems.get(finalI))
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Successfully uploaded : " + nItems.get(finalI1).getFileName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener);
        dialog.dismiss();
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reference.putFile(file)` uploads file asynchronously so don't upload all files in a `for` loop.

Instead of that create a function which uploads a file, and when a file is uploaded successfully in `onSuccess` remove the uploaded file object from the list and send the next file object for upload.

And when there is no file left in the files list `dismiss` the dialog.

It's just like a queue.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private ArrayList<NoteItem> nItems

public void uploadNotesToSTORAGE(final ArrayList<NoteItem> items, Activity activity) {
    nItems = items

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading picture...");
    dialog.show();


    if(nItems != null && !nItems.isEmpty()){
      uploadSingleNote(nItems.get(0));        //get first item
     }
}

private void uploadSingleNote(NoteItem item){
    final String id = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "";
    StorageReference reference = mStorageRef.child("notes/" + id);
    String filePath = item.getFilePath();

    reference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            StorageReference reference = mStorageRef.child("notes/" + id);
            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri dUri) {
                    item.setId(id);
                    item.setDownloadLink(dUri + "");
                    db.collection("notes").document().set(nItems.get(finalI))
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Successfully uploaded : " + item.getFileName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            nItems.remove(0);
                            if(nItems != null && !nItems.isEmpty()){
                               uploadSingleNote(nItems.get(0));        //get first item
                             }else{
                              dialog.dismiss();
                                activity.finish();
                              activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
                             }
                          }
                     });
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener);
}
```

Comment: I want an example of how to do it.